# How do I highlight commas not followed by a space in vim?

Tags: vim, vimrc

I've gotten into the habit of not appending spaces after commas in lists, when coding.

To break this habit, I thought I'd get `vim` to highlight any comma (`,`) that is not followed by a space.

So I've added this to my `.vimrc`:

```
highlight SquishedCommas ctermbg=red guibg=red
match SquishedCommas /,(?! )/
```

However, it doesn't seem to highlight anything!

Comment: Great way to break a habit!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [syntax for lookarounds in vim](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/zero-width) is different from the PCRE syntax that you appear to have assumed. Instead of `(?! )` try `\@!` i.e.

```
highlight SquishedCommas ctermbg=red guibg=red
match SquishedCommas /, \@!/
```

Comment: Hmm, I added this and sourced it but I'm still not seeing highlights. I'm wondering if my vim isn't highlighting at all for some reason? I tried `/ \@!/` to highlight anything not followed by a space and still got nothing...

Comment: Well I tested it before posting, using vim 7.4 on a LMDE (Mint/Debian) laptop - it's working for me. I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: Well I obviously have some dodgy `.vimrc` action going on so I'll have to investigate!

Comment: Please don't feel obligated to accept the answer if it's not working for you

Comment: Well I figured it's the answer to the question. I've obviously got an unrelated issue elsewhere but I'll ask another question if I can't figure it out.

Comment: Problem was I had `vim-better-whitespace` installed, which was apparently overriding the match.

Comment: @Jason glad you figured it out - thanks for the update